# My Xeon e5 1620 0 @3.6 is overheating

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, workstation

I recently bought an RTX 2060, and I installed an MSI afterburner. I noticed that my CPU heat which is XEON E5-1620 0 3.60, is overheating reaching 97 max.

I noticed also that the fan is only on 1400RPM max. I haven't replaced the thermal paste for the last 2 years.

Any idea please on how to fix that or at least increase the fan's speed because I've tried SpeedFan or BIOS with no result.

Comment: What is the stated temperature range of this CPU? I 97 is high, but not overheating for most CPUs.

Comment: https://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/3346-thermal-paste-application-benchmark-too-much-thermal-paste is your friend.

Comment: according to Intel website, the MAX temperature of this CPU is 64C